# How to disable hardware keyboard for a particular EditText?

Tags: android

HI.. This is my code in xml

```
<EditText android:longClickable="false"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:id="@+id/txt"
                    android:width="150dp" android:singleLine="true" android:text="@string/value"
                    android:inputType="none" android:cursorVisible="false" />
```

I have manually disabled soft keyboard in my application.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```

where view is the EditText. However I m unable to disable the input from hardware keyboard (slide keyboard) like the ones in droid for that particular EditText. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Why do you need an EditText without keyboard interaction? Use TextView instead

Comment: Its actually for a form.. All of them must be edittext, one particular one must be selected from a list appearing as pop up. So manual entry must be disabled. Since it must look similar to rest of form components I used EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a TextChangedListener and if the text is not one of the choices call setText("")?
[Dev Reference Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)